# Reading JavaScript content in Apache Nutch by prolonging Network Timeout

Tags: ajax, apache, nutch

I am crawling a single domain using `Apache Nutch`. However, majority of its pages are using `JavaScript/AJAX` operations to load some links I want fetched. Will prolonging network timeout setting in `nutch-site.xml` help in prolonging waiting times for the crawler (and possibly allowing the Ajax call to finish and render itself)?

Thanks!

Comment: What's stopping you from trying it & finding out for yourself?

Comment: That probably is some good advice, thanks. But is there any other more "canon" way to get such a functionality working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use nutch selenium plugin. It was recently released with nutch 1.11. Look at the protocol-selenium and protocol-interactiveselenium plugins to understand better how they are working.

Comment: I've seen this before and I guess there's no other way. Thanks!